# Image not found, yet it's on the server

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I'm currently having an issue I cannot solve on my own.

I have a simple `img` tag which has `src` attribute linking an image THAT `actually` exists. Yet the page doesn't display it and the `JavaScript` console returns an error:

[image]

It finds the error in jQuery though I'm loading the image like this:

```
<div class="login_with_fb">
    <a href="#" class="button rounded-3px"> Можеш да си направиш и регистрация чрез facebook </a>
</div>

.login_with_fb .button {
    background: #3a589b url(../img/fb_icon.png) no-repeat 10px center;
}
```

The only place I use jQuery is because the parent div is hidden and when you click on a button it sets `display: block`.

Also the image is available. And do not find any problems with other images.

Comment: create a http://jsfiddle.net/ so we can test it out

Comment: Cannot create a demo, here is the website: www.e-clinic.bg. Checkout the console.

Comment: I can see your img (http://jsfiddle.net/ZEdca/), is it in the same directory?

Comment: The only error I see in the console is about an image called select.png which in fact does not exist.

Comment: how is your directory structure?

Comment: Can you post your directory? your html file directory and image directory

Comment: You sure the image extension is png?

Comment: `css/main.css`,`img/fb_icon.png` also I'm using CodeIgniter. And the funny part is that the other images are displayed properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this on your `http://your-website.com/assets/js/phake.style.js` file

```
select_image: '../img/select.png', //image for the initial select
              ^  ^
```

Try also:

```
select_image: 'assets/img/select.png', //image for the initial select
```

Comment: Still image doesnt show and getting that error in the JS console.

Comment: @FakeHeal, try also `select_image: 'assets/img/select.png',`

Comment: Ok, the JS problem is easily fixed. I will find a way. The other two or three images I cannot understand why they do not appear. Also it doesn't return 404 error, just *failed to load resource*

Comment: @FakeHeal, I see no errors on your site anymore. Which other "two or three images" do you mean?

Comment: @FakeHeal, were do you get those errors? I don't see them on the console. I see them in the html code, there you could remove the http and the domain and have just `/assets/img/facebook_icon.png`